# Return a predicate as a lambda in Java

Tags: java, filter, lambda, java-8, predicate

In [this](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/filter-tutorial.php) online tutorial they use a lambda to filter a list of users:

```
List<User> olderUsers = users.stream().filter(u -> u.age > 30).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now I want to make a function which accepts a lambda (the `u -> u.age > 30` part) so that I can put any criterion I want inside a this lambda. But I'm a bit stuck on how to implement this. I have made an empty interface `Filter` and I made the following methods:

```
public List<User> filterUsers(Filter f, List<User users>){
    return users.stream().filter(f).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
public Filter olderThan(int age) {
    return u -> u.getAge() > age;
}
```

But this gives a number of errors.

(I made a getter of the `age`field in `user`).
Is there a way to adjust the interface `Filter` or the other methods to make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need your `Filter` type.  Just make the `filterUsers` method take a `Predicate<User>` and pass it in:

```
public List<User> filterUsers(Predicate<User> p, List<User> users) {
    return users.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This would allow you to write something like:

```
List<User> filtered = filterUsers(u -> u.age > 10, users);
```

If you wanted to make your "olderThan" thing for convenience, you can write:

```
public Predicate<User> olderThan(int age) {
    return u -> u.getAge() > age;
}
```

And then you could write:

```
List<User> filtered = filterUser(olderThan(15), users);
```

Comment: You could make the filter method more generic. Something similar to this: `public <T> List<T> filterList(Predicate<? super T> p, List<T> l)`

Comment: Great generification!

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use `Predicate` instead of `Filter`.